# Jquery-fileupload-rails not working with multiple-part form

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, jquery-file-upload, jquery-fileupload-rails

i'm trying like crazy to get this jquery-fileupload functionality to work with carrierwave:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload?autoplay=true

and its causing me all kinds of problems.  I have a 3 models - for projects, versions and layers.  Within a project, I'm trying to create both a version AND several associated layers within the same form (from the new.html.erb file in the views/versions).  I'm following Ryan Bates Railscast #381 and just can't seem to get the files to upload automatically when selected directly in the new view.  (on the new version page, if i select several layer files then click the 'create version' button, the associated layer files do upload successfully.  But in the tutorial they upload right away when selected via jquery without having to click any 'create' button.  The main difference between what he does & what i'm trying to do is he is uploading all files from the 'paintings' index page...where as I am trying to display uploaded files directly on the 'new.html.erb' form page...& then when the user clicks 'create version' the form will be creating both the new version and the new associated layers at the same time.

I hope this makes sense...my code is as follows, but please let me know if I should provide further explanation.  (I've hunted through many questions but my examples seems a bit more complex than most 'single-model' jquery-fileupload examples i've come across).

GEMFILE

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.4'
gem 'pg'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.1.1.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'faker'
gem 'bootstrap_form'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem "pundit"
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete', :git=>'git@github.com:yangbodotnet/rails3-jquery-autocomplete.git'
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.2'

gem 'rmagick', :require => 'RMagick'
gem 'carrierwave'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library & jquery UI
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
```

ROUTES.RB

```
ProductionApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  resources :projects do
    resources :versions
    match '/settings'=>'projects#settings', :via=>:get, :as=>:settings
    match '/collaboration'=>'projects#collaboration', :via=>:get, :as=>:collaboration
  end

  resources :versions do
    resources :users
  end

end
```

NEW.HTML.ERB (NEW VERSION PAGE & FORM.  This creates the new version & associated layers which are uploaded as attachments...However the files should upload and display as soon as they are selected...i.e, before the user clicks 'create'.  Or if they don't actually upload right away, I just need them to act as something of a preview of the uploads before actually clicking create...

```
<% provide(:title, 'New Version') %>

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-5 no-pad">
    <h1>Create a new version</h1>
    <%= bootstrap_form_for @version, :html => {:multipart => true}, :url => project_versions_path, :remote => true do |f| %>

      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

    <%= f.text_field :title %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>

    <div class="well">
      <h4>Drag your file uploads here:</h4>
      <%= image_tag("icon-large-grey.png", alt: "add files") %>

      <%= f.file_field :audio, multiple: true, name: "layer[audio][]", :required=>true %>

    </div>

    <%= f.button "Create Now! ", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 hidden-sm">
    <%= image_tag "shadow-vert.png" %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 no-pad">

  <!-- ------------ BELOW IS WHERE THE UPLOAD PREVIEWS SHOULD SHOW UP...but they are not ------------------------------------------------ -->

    <h1>Preview your changes & additions</h1>
    <div id="layers">
      <%= render @version.layers %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

AUDIO_UPLOADER.RB (UPLOADERS/AUDIO_UPLOADER.RB...THIS IS THE CARRIERWAVE UPLOADER FILE)

```
# encoding: utf-8

class AudioUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

VERSIONS_CONTROLLER

```
class VersionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_project

  def new
    @version = @project.versions.build(user_id: current_user.id) 
  end

  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id]) 
    @version = Version.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    # @user = User.where(:id => @version.user_id) first figure out how to set user_id on new versions (its nil now)
    @versions = Version.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @version = @project.versions.build(version_params)
    if @version.save
      @version.create_layers_with_audio(layer_audio_params) if params[:layer]
      flash[:success] = "Created successfully"
      redirect_to project_path(@project)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def find_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end

  def version_params
    params.require(:version).permit(:title, :project_id, :user_id)
  end

  def layer_audio_params
    params.require(:layer).require(:audio)
  end
end
```

VERSION.RB (VERSION MODEL)

```
class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :layers, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }

  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }

  def create_layers_with_audio(audios)
    audios.each do |au|
      self.layers.create(:audio=>au, :project_id=> self.project_id)
    end
  end
end
```

LAYERS_CONTROLLER.RB (LAYERS CONTROLLER)

```
class LayersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @layers = Layer.all
  end

  def new
    @layer = Layer.new
  end

  def show
    @layer = Layer.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @version = Version.find(params[:version_id])
    @layer = @version.layers.create(layer_params)
    # if @layer.save
      # flash[:success] = "Audio layers have been added successfully"
      # redirect_to @project
    # else
      # render 'new'
    # end
  end

  def update

  end

  def destroy

  end

  private

  # def layer_params
    # params.require(:layer).permit(:audio, :project_id, :version_id)
  # end
end
```

LAYER.RB (LAYER MODEL)

```
class Layer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :version

  validates :project_id, presence: true
  validates :version_id, presence: true
  validates :audio, presence: true

  mount_uploader :audio, AudioUploader
end
```

CREATE.JS.ERB (I BELIEVE THIS FILE MAY BE WHERE I'M GOING WRONG!)

```
<% if @layer.new_record? %>
    alert("failed to upload layer: <%= j @layer.errors.full_messages.join(', ').html_safe %>");
<% else %>
    $("#layers").append("<%= j render(@layer) %>");
<% end %>
```

_LAYER.HTML.ERB (_LAYER PARTIAL)

```
<li>

  <div class="bg-add">
    <%= layer.audio %>
  </div>

</li>
```

APPLICATION.JS (ASSETS/JAVASCRIPTS)

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrapValidator/dist/js/bootstrapValidator.min
//= require_tree .
```

APPLICATION.CSS (ASSETS/STYLESHEETS)

```
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery.ui.all
 *= require bootstrapValidator/dist/css/bootstrapValidator.min
 *= require_tree .
```

VERSIONS.JS.COFFEE (APP/ASSETS/JAVASCRIPTS...)

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/
jQuery ->
  $('#new_layer').fileupload()
    dataType: "script"
```

LAYERS.JS.COFFEE (APP/ASSETS/JAVASCRIPTS...wasn't sure if this js should go in layers or versions since the form creates both...so i tried including in both)

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/
jQuery ->
  $('#new_layer').fileupload()
    dataType: "script"
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using jquery file upload just try the remotepart gem, which will make our rails remote form to carry the file. Please refer http://os.alfajango.com/remotipart/.

Comment: thanks Mohanraj, is there a demo of this I can see in the browser?  (for instance jquery-fileupload demos the functionality right from http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Comment: When you add //= require jquery.remotipart line to application.js automatically your form will get ability to support file field. In the above mentioned url includes the demo app as well

Comment: Mohanraj, added the remotipart gem and added the require file to the application.js.  It still doesn't upload automatically.  I added the :remote => true also as per the documentation. Can you provide specifics of where i need to add code?